# Cast HashMap<String, Object> to List<Map<String, Object>>

Tags: java, casting, linked-list, hashmap

```
HashMap<String, Object> hm  has data like  { "A": {'key1' : 'value1', 'key2' : 'value2'}, "B": {'key1' : 'value3', 'key2' : 'value4'}}
```

I want to convert this to `List<Map<String, Object>>` like `[{'key1' : 'value1', 'key2' : 'value2'}, {'key1' : 'value3', 'key2' : 'value4'}]`

Is there any way I can do this without iterating whole HashMap?

I tried: `new LinkedList<Map<String, Object>>(hm.values)  and (List<Map<String, Object>>) (hm.values) bt didn't work.`

```
I am to convert this using
(List<Map<String,Object>>)hm.values().stream().map(c-> (Map<String,Object>)c).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

but for this I have to iterate whole hashmap.

Comment: Why do you need a list, and not a collection?
For starters, your hm type is wrong. It should be HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>, and then you get Collection<Map<String, String>> coll =  hm.values() which is probably what you need.

Comment: The values in the hasmap you have are arbitrary objects: `HashMap<String, Object>`. You can easily get a list of the values, but it will be a list of arbitrary objects: `List<Object>`. Is that good enough for you?

Comment: @D(List<Map<String,Object>>)hm.values().stream().
                    map(c-> (Map<String,Object>)c).
                    collect(Collectors.toList());